# Tennis dataset of hawk-eye or other stats

Tags: sports

Is there any available tennis dataset regarding hawk-eye tracking statistics?

Other than the historical data on the official ATP site are there out any other free db of tennis statistics analyzing different variables?

Answer (score 2):

From the ReplicationWiki (that I founded) I know of an economics paper and a replication of it on the distribution of serves at Wimbledon to understand the strategy how to vary: [http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Minimax_Play_at_Wimbledon:*Comment*(AER_2007)](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Minimax_Play_at_Wimbledon:_Comment_(AER_2007))